# Complicated Recurrence Pattern in Microsoft Graph Calendar API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I have a Master event (SeriesMaster) and need to assign a batch of occurrences, which do not fall into any recurrence pattern. Rather each of them just have some date. As far as I understand, to make an event with various instances I **must** have a recurrence pattern.
Is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: There isn't a lot of information to go on here. What recurrence pattern are you looking for? If there isn't a pattern then it doesn't sound like a recurring meeting.

Comment: Sorry if it was misleading. In my case I have an event with several absolute dates. So it is recurring but without a pattern. All the instances must behave as a series, i.e. deleting an occurrence would delete all occurrences in this series.